# Multiple kinematics solver for the manipulator

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, ros-melodic, ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

below you can find my kinematics.yaml file. Since my robot only has 5 DoF and the IK solver has sometimes has probelms with finding solutions. So the position_only_ik parameter is set to true.

However, the ik-solver should at least try to find a solution according to the given 4D cartesian parameters (x,y,z,pitch). So I am wondering if I could use multiple kinematics solver or change the position_only_ik value online so that I can tell the robot: **Use solver 1 with position_only_ik:false and if you failed use solver 2 with position_only_ik:true**.

> robot_arm:
> kinematics_solver:
> trac_ik_kinematics_plugin/TRAC_IKKinematicsPlugin

> kinematics_solver_search_resolution:
> 0.05
> kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.005
> position_only_ik: true

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358874/multiple-kinematics-solver-for-the-manipulator/) by [xman236](https://answers.ros.org/users/47615/xman236/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2020-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> So I am wondering if I could use multiple kinematics solver [..] so that I can tell the robot: Use solver 1 with position_only_ik:false and if you failed use solver 2 with position_only_ik:true.

No, this is currently not supported by MoveIt.

A workaround could be to implement an IK solver yourself which realises this behaviour (ie: uses multiple IK solvers internally itself).

That way MoveIt would only see a single solver, but you'd still achieve the behaviour you describe.

> change the position_only_ik value online

Afaik `position_only_ik` is not a `dynamic_reconfigure` parameter, so this would also not be supported.

It would be easy to check though: just start MoveIt, start `rqt_reconfigure` and see whether that parameter is there.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0